# Take a picture and record video react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My goal is to record a video when holding down the camera button but also take a picture when tapping the camera button. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
  const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState(false);

  const cameraRef = createRef();

  const onLongPressButton = () => {
    setRecording(true);
    startRecord();
  };


  const startRecord = async () => {
    setRecording(true);
    console.log("RECORDING");
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      setRecording(true);
      const recordedVideo = await cameraRef.current.recordAsync();
      setVideo(recordedVideo);
    }
  };

  const stopRecord = async () => {
    await cameraRef.current.stopRecording();
    console.log("STOP RECORDING");
    setRecording(false);
  };


  const handlePhoto = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current && !recording) {
      let photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync({});
      console.log(photo.uri);
    } else {
      stopRecord();
    }
  };
```

And here is my camera button component:

```js
<Circle
onPress={handlePhoto}
onLongPress={onLongPressButton}
onPressOut={async () => {
await cameraRef.current.stopRecording();
console.log("STOP RECORDING");
setRecording(false);
}}
delayLongPress={50}
              />
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue you are having? Is it not possible to tap while recording, does recording stop when you tap to take photo, does it continue recording but doesn't take the photo?

Comment: @MarekLisik Currently, the code takes a photo.  However, when I use the onLongPress, the record function fires but the promise isn't returned when I stop recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be not with the camera or touch handling, but with the use of `createRef` instead of `useRef`. Note that in your case, used within a function component, `createRef` will create a new ref on every render. Replace it with `useRef` so that the reference remains the same across renders:

```
 const cameraRef = useRef();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I open you snacks, it shows a blank page. Can you please check?

Comment: @RogerStaxx it works fine on my end (running them on a device) - that said, I've updated the answer to include the only change I made.